# MySQL: select phones that belongs to different users

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a task that I can't solve by myself because of lack of experience, and I really need for help.

Let's assume we have a table with the following fields: "phone_number" and "user_id". The goal is to find numbers that belongs to more then one user.

The result should looks like that:

> +---------------------------+---------------------------------+
>   |     phone_number     |     counts     |     users     |
>   +---------------------------+---------------------------------+
>   |     (xxx)xxx-xxx         |         5          |     1, 5, 9    |
>   +---------------------------+---------------------------------+

*phone_number* - the phone number that repeats
*counts* - how many times that number repeats
*users* - ids of the users having this number, separated by comma. Example (1, 5, 9)

I have the following query that finds number duplicates, but I need to compare it with id of the user. And get ids of users this number duplicated.

```
SELECT `number`, count(`number`) AS `count`, `user_id` from `phones` 
GROUP BY `number` HAVING `count` > 1
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` on `user_id` column for the said desired result

**Example**:

```
select  `number` as `phone_number`, 
        count( `number` ) AS `counts`,
        group_concat( `user_id` ) as `users`
  from  `phones` 
 group  by `number` 
having  `counts` > 1
```